# javascript date object is causing a interesting issue in my calendar app

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to make a calendar page using javascript. I want to proceed step by step by solving the problems. If I can solve this problem, I will solve the other parts.

Note:You can see the problem on the snippet.

Note2: Since the first days of some months start in the middle of the week, I will make the previous days blank in the calendar.

**That's the problem:** While the days of all months are located where they should be, **August remains empty.** When I try the `time.setMonth(8)` and `time.setDate(0)` operations on another console, it gets output on the last day of August, while it goes directly to September in the program cycle and **writes September twice.**

I apply the `time.setDate(0)` transaction on that month to find out how many days the month lasts.

**JS code**

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
const calender = document.querySelector(".calender");
var calenderInner = "";
monthNames.forEach(name => {
    calenderInner += `<div class="month" data-month="${name.substring(0,3)}"><h1>${name}</h1></div>`;
    calender.innerHTML = calenderInner;
});

const monthDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".month");
monthDivs.forEach(month => {
    var daysHTML = "<div class='days'>";
    days.forEach(day =>{
    daysHTML+= `<div class="day" data-month="${month.dataset.month}" data-day="${day}"><p>${day}</p></div>`;
}); 
month.innerHTML += daysHTML + "</div>";
});
var time = new Date();
monthDivs.forEach((month, index) => {
    time.setMonth(index + 1);
    time.setDate(0);
    var endDayOfMonth = time.getDate();
    for(let i = 1; i <= endDayOfMonth; i++)
    {
        time.setDate(i);
        const currentDay = document.querySelector(`[data-month=${time.toDateString().split(" ")[1]}][data-day=${time.toDateString().split(" ")[0]}]`);
        let dayCircle = document.createElement("div");
        dayCircle.innerHTML = i;
        dayCircle.className = "dayCircles";
        currentDay.appendChild(dayCircle);
    }
});
```

```css
.main{
    background:#bbbbbb;
    width:1000px;
    height:1560px;
    margin:50px auto}
  .head{
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .head > p{font-size:25px}
  .moods{
    background:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .calender{
    padding:10px;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-between;
  }
  .month{
    background:white;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
  }
  .days{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  .day{
    background:white;
    height:50px;
  }
  .day > p{
    border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .dayCircles{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    margin: 1px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .emptyDayCircles{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    bacground:gray;
    margin: 1px auto;
    border-radius:50%
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body><div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="head">
          <h1>2020 Mood Calendar</h1>
          
          <div class="moods">
            <div class="mood1"></div>
            <div class="mood2"></div>
            <div class="mood3"></div>
            <div class="mood4"></div>
            <div class="mood5"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="calender">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it depends on **GMT + 3**, because **August is the 8th month** and **8 x (+3) = 24 hours, so 1 day**. When extra days are **added to the end of 30 days**, it moves to the **next month**. I wonder if that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it! I have prevented deviations due to GMT +3 by creating a new date object each time in the loop.

```
.
.
.
monthDivs.forEach((month, index) => {
    var time = new Date();
    time.setMonth(index + 1);
    time.setDate(0);
    var endDayOfMonth = time.getDate();
    time = new Date();
    time.setMonth(index);
    const currentDay = document.querySelector(`div[data-month-inner=${time.toDateString().split(" ")[1]}]`);
    let firstDayOfMonth = time.getDay();
    for(let i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++)
    {
        const dayCircle = document.createElement("div");
        dayCircle.className = "dayCircles";
        currentDay.appendChild(dayCircle);
    }
    console.log(currentDay);
    for(let i = 1; i <= endDayOfMonth; i++)
    {   
        console.log()
        const dayCircle = document.createElement("div");
        dayCircle.className = "dayCircles";
        time.setDate(i);
        time.setMonth(index + 1);
        dayCircle.innerHTML = `<div class="dayCirclesInner">${i}</div>`
        currentDay.appendChild(dayCircle);
        if(index == 11 && i == endDayOfMonth)
        {
            const dayCircle = document.createElement("div");
        dayCircle.className = "dayCircles";
        dayCircle.innerHTML = `<div class="dayCirclesInner" style="background-color:green">1</div>`;
        currentDay.appendChild(dayCircle);
        }
    }
});
```